# kde themes doesn't appear after download and install

Tags: kde, desktop-environments

hey everyone i just downloaded the new theme for my my KDE from  http://kde-look.org/.
in other tutorial they that extract the package and copy it into /home/username/.kde/share/apps/desktop/theme.but when i when i do that the theme doesn't appear in the workspace appearance.

can anybody help me solve this problem?

Comment: Could you add the theme name & url. So I can test it at here.

Comment: http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/dbozMOD?content=163705

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Window decoration**

Your link is pointing to the Beryl Emerald window decoration. The window decoration is appearance of window borders, titlebars and buttons.

[image]

The Emerald themes are not native KDE window decorations. To use the Emerald themes you will need a theme engine. An engine to use the Emerald themes is the Smaragd: http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Smaragd+(Emerald+for+KDE)?content=125162 .

**Style/Theme**

Inside the windows the KDE/Qt widgets have the style/theme (buttons, scrollbars, tabs, and menus). The KDE-Look Themes/Styles: http://kde-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=9

There is the http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/dboz_color%26qt?content=164247 .

[image]

It is using the Qt-Curve: http://kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=40492.

The Qt Curve is in the official Ubuntu repositories:

```
:~$ apt-cache show qtcurve
Package: qtcurve
Priority: optional
Section: universe/kde
...
Description-en: Unified window decoration for KDE and GTK+ (meta-package)
 This package installs all packages related with QtCurve:
  * kde-style-qtcurve
  * kwin-style-qtcurve
  * gtk2-engines-qtcurve
  * qtcurve-l10n
 .
 QtCurve is a set of widget styles for KDE and GTK+. It provides a consistent
 look between KDE and GTK+ applications, which is easy on the eyes and visually
 pleasing.

Homepage: http://www.kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=40492
```

**KDE plasma desktop themes**

The KDE plasma desktop themes are using the ...share/apps/desktoptheme.

Desktop themes:

- http://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Workspace_Appearance
- http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/ThemeDetails

Extra desktop themes from the KDE-Look: http://kde-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=76

**Q&A**

Q:

> yes, i have installed smaragd from the source code,now how to use it
>   to customize the desktop?

A:

As the Smaragd page tells:

> The *.emerald theme file has to be extracted to $HOME/.emerald/theme

[image]

KDE System Settings > Workspace Appearance > Window Decorations > Smaragd and click the Apply button.

[image]

You may need to log out or restart.

Comment: yes, i have installed smaragd from the source code,now how to use it to customize the desktop?

Comment: Added an Q&A section

Comment: sorry i have too many question.
i don't know how to extract file *.emerald
how can i extract tha file?

Comment: First you make the '.emerald' (note the dot) folder to your home directory. After that you make the 'theme' folder to the '.emerald' folder. At last you unpack the the theme to the $HOME/.emerald/theme. The theme consist a 'ini' file and several picture files (png).

Comment: KDE archiving tool page from the KDE UserBase: http://userbase.kde.org/Ark. The 163705-dbozMOD.gz will unpack to the 163705-dbozMOD. The 163705-dbozMOD will unpack to the ini&png files.